# Databricks REST API returns HTTP 400 error (with a AAD Access Token)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, azure-databricks

I am trying to access to the REST API of Databricks with an Active Directoy Access Token.

To do so, from the **Active Directory -> App Registration -> AAD App:**

In API Permissions I have added the AzureDatabricks API

[image]

Then I am trying to access to any data from the Databricks REST API, but always I am getting the same error:

**"io.jsonwebtoken.security.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted."**

One of the endpoint I am trying to request is:

```
https://adb-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/token/list
```

This Access Token let me do requests to my Graph API, so I guess the token is OK. If my Access Token expires, returns that the token has expired...

To do all tries I am using Insomnia (similar to Postman).

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to do something more?

Thanks beforehand

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to request the Databricks API, the access token can not request the Graph API.
This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/app-aad-token#--authorization-code-flow-interactive) shows to get access token about Databricks.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<client-id>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=<redirect URI in encoded format: e.g., http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost>
&response_mode=query
&resource=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d
&state=<a random number or some encoded info>
```

Make sure `resource` is `2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d`(the appid of 
user_impersonation permission). And you will get `code` that will be used in the next step.

```
POST  https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id={client id}
&scope=https://azuredatabricks.net//user_impersonation
&code={code}
&redirect_uri=http://localhost
&grant_type=authorization_code
```

You could use the access token to request the Databricks API.

On the other hand, it is not recommended to use Postman when it is related to login.